# $(this) child element css change not working at all

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, this

I have a little question.

```
 $('.item').mouseenter(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
  $(this).find('.item-overlay').css('z-index', '-1');
}, 300);
}).mouseleave(function() {
  $(this).find('.item-overlay').css('z-index', '');
});

 <div class="item">
    <div class="item-overlay">
    </div>

    <iframe>...</iframe>

 </div>
```

Everything works fine, except one small thing. z-index isn't changing. Can you guys help me out with this?
I've also tried with "next", "child", "find" - none worked :(

Comment: Is your element positioned absolute ?

Comment: .item is relative, .item-overlay is absolute... T.J Crowder's solution works like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`this` within the function you're passing `setTimeout` will be `window`, not the element. (`this` depends on how a function is called, not where it's used.)

You can save the `this` value the event handler got (or actually, as you're going to jQuery-wrap it, just do that with a `var` outside the `setTimeout` function), e.g.:

```
$('.item').mouseenter(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $this.find('.item-overlay').css('z-index', '-1');
    }, 300);
    // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need absolute positioning for ".item-overlay"

Answer (score 0):

I think *this* is out of your function. So, you can set var that = this; before setTimeout. And use that instead of this.

*Callback* stuff