# When items are hovered fast they're not returning to its default state

Tags: jquery, hover, mouseenter, mouseleave

With reference to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17964192/this-child-element-css-change-not-working-at-all)

When mouseenter on each item, its overlay disappearing, when mouseleave - the overlay shows.

When I have more items, and **fast** hovering on them randomly, they're not returning to it's previous state. It's quite annoying :/

Why is that?

```
 $('.item').mouseenter(function () {
var $this = $(this);
setTimeout(function () {
    $this.find('.item-overlay').css('z-index', '-1');
}, 300);
 }).mouseleave(function () {
$(this).find('.item-overlay').css('z-index', '1');
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/w3Gha/

Comment: Create a fiddle or send us your code because it's difficult to help you with so little information.

Comment: seems like a timer  could solve your problem. e.g. when enter a item start a tiemout from about 500 msecs and after its completed execute the hover function. fast hovers will be excluded this way.

Comment: its hard without code, the problem could also be that the leave handler wont trigger right

Comment: Link to jsfiddle updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with [hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/): http://jsfiddle.net/KfS9H/

```
  $(".item").hover(
      function () {
           $(this).find('.item-overlay').stop().css('z-index', '-1');
      },
      function () {
           $(this).find('.item-overlay').stop().css('z-index', '1');
      }
  );
```

Comment: You are BOSS :) Thank u :)

Answer (score 0):

### Try this out:- http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/w3Gha/1/

Use `$('.item iframe')` instead of `$('.item')`.

**JS:-**

```
$('.item iframe').mouseenter(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    setTimeout(function () {
        $this.find('.item-overlay').css('z-index', '-1');
    }, 300);
}).mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).find('.item-overlay').css('z-index', '1');
});
```

Comment: But if you are adding a layer on the top the div/iframe, you won't be able to click on the content below that.

Comment: That's why i'm tryin to z-index: -1 on the overlay